# What is the ownership of *self in matching expression for impl of struct in rust

Tags: rust

I am using example from [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html)

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum List {
    Cons(i32, RefCell<Rc<List>>),
    Nil,
}

impl List {
    fn tail(&self) -> Option<&RefCell<Rc<List>>> {
        match *self {
            Cons(_, ref item) => Some(item),
            Nil => None,
        }
    }
}
```

Given the function signature is `&self` ,  `self` is of reference type pointing at `List` and `*self` is the `List` instance itself.

But I remember `match` also take ownership of the object it is matching, so doesn't that cause problem to the struct because the `List` instance is move to `match` and not give back?

Also isn't `&self` immutable, why are we able to move `self` to `match`?

Answer (score 3):

`match` *by itself* does not move anything. Moves, copies or borrows happen in the branches of the `match`.
Example:

```
let s = "test".to_string();
let a = s; // this is a move
// println!("{}", s); // ... so this is a "use after move" compilation error
```

but if we do:

```
match a { // this is allowed, a does not move anywhere
    // but in the branch...
    // this is an error: it would move a to res
    // res if res == "test".to_string() => "ok",
    // ^^^ moves value into pattern guard
    ref res if res == "test" => "ok", // with ref it's fine (we're
    // taking a by reference)
    _ => "ko",
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=21d496bac120342de82e7815430f671c&version=stable)

Note that you might indeed run into ownership issues in the `match`, but they are typically due to something you're doing after the `match` keyword.

For instance this fails:

```
// let's break the string in two pieces
match a.split_off(2)
//    ^ cannot borrow mutably
```

but it's because of the `split_off` that takes `&mut self`, not the `match` on the result.